# is Joomla 1.5.26 compatible with php 5.3.13?

Tags: joomla

My host seems to think not, and says I have to upgrade. But that is quite a leap that I would rather not take.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jelmar,

Sure, since Joomla 1.5.15 + are compatible with PHP 5.3.

*Note that just the OpenID library is not yet compatible with PHP 5.3.

As Requirements for Joomla 1.5.x in link [TECHNICAL REQUIREMENTS](http://www.joomla.org/technical-requirements.html)

Show:
Requirements for Joomla 1.5.x

Software PHP*
Recommended 5.2 +